# YouTube on iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, facebook, youtube, ios-simulator

Hey guys
I was wondering if there is a way to get the youtube app into the iOS Simulator? I am almost done with my project and I need to test some iPhone URL Schemes that I have installed into my project (i.e. launching Facebook, YouTube, AppStore) all those kind of apps that I need to test that aren't in the iOS Simulator, hope someone knows, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no there is no way to install apps on ios simulator.